# Using Profile Properties in ClientInterceptor

Tags: java, spring

I have a `profiles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Local -->
    <beans profile="local">
        <util:properties id="localProperties">
            <prop key="property">localProperty</prop>
        </util:properties>
        <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="localProperties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
    </beans>

    <!-- Dev -->
    <beans profile="dev">
        <util:properties id="devProperties">
            <prop key="property">devProperty</prop>
        </util:properties>
        <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="devProperties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
    </beans>

</beans>
```

and I have a `org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor` that I want to use values from `profiles.xml`:

```
@Component
public class HeaderInjector implements ClientInterceptor {

    @Value("${property}")
    private static String someProperty;

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext)
            throws WebServiceClientException {
        //want to use someProperty here based on value from profiles.xml
    }

}
```

How can I do this? I tried adding `@ImportResource("profiles.xml")` at the top of the class like

```
@Component
@ImportResource("profiles.xml")
public class SoapLeadPipeHeaderInjector implements ClientInterceptor {
```

but `someProperty` never gets set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is nothing about [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) in your question, so be careful with choosing tags for questions.

`@ImportResource("profiles.xml")` can be applied on the `@Configuration` class if you start application context from annotations.

If your main entry point is XML configuration, your `@Component` must be scanned via `<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>` then.

See more info in the Spring Framework [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).

Comment: Adding `<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>` to my entry XML configuration was part of the solution. I also had to remove `static` from `private static String someProperty`.